# Сделать так, чтобы :hover не срабатывал на дочернем элементе

Tags: css

```css
#bg:hover #close{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='bg'>
  <div id='content'>
    <button id='close'></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это всплывающее окно. `#bg` - темный полупрозрачный фон на все окно браузера, `#content` - собственно окно с контентом и `#close` - кнопка закрытия. Как сделать так, чтобы `#close` окрашивался в красный только когда курсор выходит за `#content`. Сейчас он срабатывает везде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#bg {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#bg:hover #close {
  background: red;
}

#content:hover #close {
  background: initial;
}

#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='bg'>
  <div id='content'>
    <button id='close'>Закрыть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Повесит ховер на "#content #close". И лучше не стилизовать по id

Comment: Да, это рабочий вариант, но по сути это перезапись bg. Я так понял он хочет совсем его отключить.

Answer (score 2):

Можно переопределить фон по умолчанию другим селектором:

```css
#bg:hover #close { background: red;}
#content:hover #close {background: initial;}
#content{border: solid 1px silver}
```

```html
<div id='bg'>
  <div id='content'>
    <button id='close'>Close</button>
    <p>Content
  </div>
  <p> Background
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно сделать обратный вариант, так как у тебя dg на всю страницу

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
}

#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#content:hover #close {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#close {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='bg'>
  <div id='content'>
    <button id='close'>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В CSS - не получится. Это свойство наследуется всеми потомками. Можно реализовать только средствами JS путем подвешивания классов при наведении на псевдородитеся.

Comment: @Air, подобные эмоции излишни. be nice

Comment: @vp_arth, согласен...

Comment: @Air Тема звучит как: "Сделать так, чтобы :hover не срабатывал на дочернем элементе" Почитайте мат часть, дочерние объекты наследуют свойства родителя и можно заменить их но не отключить. В чем я не прав?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, ты прав, но выйти из сутуации можно...  если бы не возможно было вообще, то даже в этом случае, подобный ответ, как твой, желательно реализовать,  как коммент....

Comment: к сожалению, в этом ответе не содержится решения проблемы