# :hover не применять для дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css, hover

Есть элемент

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: #28292d;
  font-family: Roboto, "sans-serif", Arial;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -220px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #ffdd47;
}

.myclass:hover {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <div class="push">
    <!--код!-->
  </div>
  <!--код!-->
</div>
```

Соответственно, при наведении на элемент мышкой, он всплывает из-под страницы полностью

Дочерний элемент класса "push" будет находиться вне этого элемента, чуть выше

Как сделать так, чтобы к нему не применялся :hover родительского элемента?

То есть, при наведении мыши на дочерний элемент, родительский и дочерний элемент не всплывали?

Comment: А еще лучше, чтоб при этом не менялась их позиция

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать так, чтобы :hover не срабатывал на дочернем элементе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738475/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-hover-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

В случае, если дочерний элемент вообще не должен никак реагировать на события мыши, то можно использовать на нем pointer-events: none;

```css
.container {
  background-color: #28292d;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #ccc; 
}

.container:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  bottom: -40px;
  background-color: green;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
container
    <div class="item">
        Элемент внутри container
    </div>
<!--код!-->
</div>
```

Comment: @humster_spb Как это ничего не измениться? Судя по задаче, внутренний элемент вынесен за пределы блока и необходимо, чтобы при наведении на этот элемент, блок не анимировался, а анимировался только если навели на сам блок. Я наехал частью внутреннего блока на родителя, чтобы продемонстрировать как это событие мыши реагирует на внутренний элемент за пределами родителя. Возможно я не так понял вопрос, но в том случае что я описал, мы получаем необходимый результат

Comment: а, не, всё ок - сорри ) это я смотрел Ваш пример, а думал про всплытие

Comment: Да, почти помогло)
И я так понимаю, нет способов оставить только клик в событиях мыши

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев Если вы более точно опишите задачу, мы вам подскажем, иначе видите мы сами друг друга не понимаем.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правильно поняли задачу)

Дочерний элемент - это всплывающее сообщение с крестиком закрытия.

Больше не на что там нажимать. Если б можно было нажать на крестик, чтоб не всплывало при этом все - было бы здорово)

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев В данном случае pointer-events: none; отменяет все события мыши, если все таки нужна какая-то реакция, тогда необходимо либо изменить верстку, либо применить js. Возможно, если никто не предложит решения, чуть позже напишу, но сейчас нет времени.

Comment: Понял)
ну изменить верстку/применить js и сами могем